# How do I write "for item in list not in other_list" in one line using Python?

Tags: python, list, optimization, for-loop, conditional-statements

I want to make a loop for items in `list` that are not present in `other_list`, in one line. Something like this:

```
>>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> other_list = ['a', 'd']
>>> for item in list not in other_list:
...     print item
...
b
c
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for item in (i for i in my_list if i not in other_list):
    print item
```

Its a bit more verbose, but its just as efficient, as it only renders each next element on the following loop.

Answer (score 2):

Using set (which might do more than what you actually want to do) :

```
for item in set(list)-set(other_list):
     print item
```

Comment: Which crushes order and duplication.

Comment: That's part of "doing more" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A third option: `for i in filter(lambda x: x not in b, a): print(i)`

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension is your friend

```
>>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> other_list = ['a', 'd']
>>> [x for x in list if x not in other_list]
['b', 'c']
```

also dont name things "list"